# How to split string into array

Tags: c#-4.0

I have this string:

```
string s = "83#design point 1#nominal#376.879#17.498#1.0768#1780#0.8|84#design point 2#reduced speed and SG#376.879#17.498#1.0768#1000#0.5|85#design point 3#different point#107.68#20.19#0.672998#1780#0.8";
```

The above string has 3 records, each record separated by pipe (`|`). I want to split these records into an array, so after seperated by pipe I will have strings like below:

```
83#design point 1#nominal#376.879#17.498#1.0768#1780#0.8
84#design point 2#reduced speed and SG#376.879#17.498#1.0768#1000#0.5
85#design point 3#different point#107.68#20.19#0.672998#1780#0.8
```

Then I want `376.879,376.879,107.68` in 1 array. Same other values also I want in different arrays, eg `17.498,17.498,20.19` for the next section.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

```
var data = s.Split('|').
    Select(a => a.Split('#').
                  Skip(3).Take(3).
                  Select(d => double.Parse(d)).
                  ToArray()
    ).Select(d =>
```

And then pivot it like this:

```
var result = new double[][]{        
    data.Select(d => d[0]).ToArray(),
    data.Select(d => d[1]).ToArray(),
    data.Select(d => d[2]).ToArray()
};
```

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/RzTkkG

Comment: thanks joel for the answer but i want  different i am changing the values of the string 
eg string s = "83#design point 1#nominal#376.879#17.498#1.0768#1780#0.8|84#design point 2#reduced speed and SG#3.879#10.498#3.0768#1000#0.5|85#design point 3#different point#107.68#20.19#0.672998#1780#0.8";
376.879(From the first),3.879(from the second),107.68(from the third) like that for other also

Comment: @ManishShende Ah, I see you want to pivot the results. That's usually a mistake (keeping arrays grouped by index is an _anti-pattern_ or code smell), but updated.